# Using custom output in Django-Autocomplete-Light

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to use a custom string for the output for django-autocomplete-light. DAL currently returns the models' **str** or **unicode**. I would like to return a particular field on the searches rather than the str or unicode methods.

For example, if my model is fruit defined as such:

```
class Fruits(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.quantity
```

I would like to return a string that shows both the quantity and the name such as: "Banana-13" as one choice, and "Apple-10" as another, etc.

I can add the string as a field to the model, but I cannot have this new "joined" field as the str or unicode.

Comment: Why you don't want to change `self.quantity` to `self.name` ?

Comment: Hello Raja,

Thank you for the fast response! I actually made a mistake in my original post that did not 100% specify the problem. I have editted the original post with some more information. I want to actually return a string that contains some information from both fields. I can't change the str or unicodes of the model to this new type of string that I would like to return.